# Radio Button drawable button image not showing completely

Tags: android, xml

I am Using radio button and set drable images as button, but my images not showing compltely in a given width and height of radio button

[The image i am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zQ4q.jpg)

xml:

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/RadioButton"
                >

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/Sell"
                    android:button="@drawable/for_sell"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"

                    />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/Rent" />
```

Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/builder" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/builder_color" />
```

and my[Resulting Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OYSF.png)

Comment: JPEG files are not resizable. It appears the way it is. If you want a drawable that fits the layout, I suggest you look into 9-Patches.

Comment: @TheSunshinator if i use 9 patch the image should resized to my given width and height..?